# elasticserach / allow text and object in the same field

Tags: elasticsearch

Good afternoon people

I am testing the elasticserach to store an application's log, but the data is very variable so in one moment a field can be TEXT and the other time can be OBJECT.
How do I set this up in elasticsearch?

Example of two documents, when I send the second it generates an error since the field became TEXT.

First document:

> {
>     "@timestamp": "2020-01-28T16:12:00.753Z",
>     "mensagem": "teste"
>   }

Second document:

> {
>     "@timestamp": "2020-01-28T16:12:00.753Z",
>     "mensagem": {
>       "campo1": "AAAA",
>       "campo2": "BBBB"
>     }
>   }

Comment: you can't do that

Comment: Agreed, this is not possible in Elasticsearch, and it doesn't really make sense from a data management viewpoint either. However, you might be able to leverage [ingest processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) in order to make sure that all your data is properly typed (i.e. properly transformed to an `object` type) before being ingested.

Comment: My goal is to store my application logs, and in these logs, I have data from different sources, where the type of data changes a lot